# TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable, why?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, int

Why am I getting this error? The error seems to be in the line calling 'for i in range' but I cannot see why this would be an error...I have quit the kernel in case something is hiding in i.

My code is as follows:

```
import os, sys
import numpy
from matplotlib import pylab, pyplot, cm
from math import pi
from skimage import io


image = numpy.ones([44,44],dtype = float)
imrange = len(image)

#Initialize empty residue map
residue_map = numpy.empty([imrange-2,imrange-2],dtype = float)

#Calculate the residues for each point following formula (1) in He paper
for i in range (1,int(imrange-1)):
    for j in range (1,int(imrange-1)):
        value = (image[i+1][j] - image[i][j]) + (image[i+1][j+1] - 
image[i+1][j]) + (image[i][j+1] - image[i+1][j+1]) + (image[i][j] - image[i][j+1])
        if value/2./pi > 0:
            residue_map[i-1][j-1] = 1.
        elif value/2./pi == 0:
            residue_map[i-1][j-1] = 0.
        else:
            residue_map[i-1][j-1] = -1.
```

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you post hthe full error message?

Comment: TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable in line 'for i in range (1,int(imrange-1)):'

Answer (score -1):

Another case of being a beginner in python....the code above works as I had defined a range = numpy.max(image) - numpy.min(image) and then used range again in the loop, hence the error!!

Comment: So, is the code working now after you have removed that line to use range?

Comment: Never use reserved keywords as variable names. Also include this line in question so that people understand what caused the problem..